# sprintf scaling integers. 123 print as 12,3

Tags: c, arduino

I have an integer, representing tenths. 
Instead of dividing by 10, thereby introducing rounding errors (and wasting time), is there a quick way of adding a decimal point before the last digit?

Some magic like

```
snprintf(dest,len,"%d4.-1", 123) resulting in 12.3
```

The reason is to avoid rounding errors, for instance in money, where the amount is calculated internally as integer cents, not fractions of £, € or $.

If I remember my COBOL correctly, here it is possible to specify a format like 9,990.00 which makes 1234 be printed as 12.34 and 1 as 0.01.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  uint16_t i16 = 0;
  float f = 998;
  for (i16 = 998; i16 < 1011; i16++) {
    Serial.print(i16 / 1000);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(f / 1000);
    Serial.printf("  %0.3f %0.3f %0.7f\n",i16/1000,f/1000,f/1000);
    f = f + 1;
  }
}
```

An int / 10 is still an int, so 123/10 = 12.

Strangely `fprint("%0.2f",123/10)` prints `0.00`

`0 1.00  0.000 0.998 0.9980000
0 1.00  0.000 0.999 0.9990000
1 1.00  0.000 1.000 1.0000000
1 1.00  0.000 1.001 1.0010000
1 1.00  0.000 1.002 1.0020000
1 1.00  0.000 1.003 1.0030000
1 1.00  0.000 1.004 1.0039999  <--- Rounding error
1 1.00  0.000 1.005 1.0050000
1 1.01  0.000 1.006 1.0060000
1 1.01  0.000 1.007 1.0070000
1 1.01  0.000 1.008 1.0080000
1 1.01  0.000 1.009 1.0089999  <--- Rounding error 
1 1.01  0.000 1.010 1.0100000`

a %0.6f does not give rounding errors, but %0.7f does.

So for doing fractional ints, it would have been nice to have an integer format with a decimal point shifted in.

Using floats can give some funny results sometimes, just yesterday I saw "The water is expected to rise between 10.000000002 and 12 feet".

Comment: You can divide by 10 and use one decimal point of precision..what's the problem?

Comment: 123/10 = 12. printf("%01f",123/10) = 0.0

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enough space in `dest`!

```
int n = snprintf(dest, len, "%d", 123);
dest[n + 1] = 0;
dest[n] = dest[n - 1];
dest[n - 1] = '.';
```

or, saving one line of code (thanks to @bruno)

```
int n = snprintf(dest, len, "%d#", 123);
dest[n - 1] = dest[n - 2];
dest[n - 2] = '.';
```

Comment: `int n = snprintf(dest, len, "%d.", 123); dest[n - 1] = dest[n - 2] ; dest[n - 2] = '.';` you save one line :-)

Comment: Good idea, @bruno. Incorporated into my answer, thanks.

Comment: I was about to answer with that when I saw you did ;-)

Comment: is sad a swap char (inline) doesn't exist, else save again a line `int n = snprintf(dest, len, "%d.", 123); swap(dest + n - 1, dest + n - 2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
snprintf (dest, len, "%3d.%01d", 123/10, 123%10)
```

Comment: This is using division, which was trying to avoid.

Comment: Integer division != floating point division. You can test it, probably 100 times faster. Give a better suggestion, please.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with `fprint("%0.2f",123/10)` OP code has undefined behavior due to a mismatch between the `double` type expected by the `%f` conversion specifier and the `int` value `123/10`.

Integer division is well-defined and does not suffer from rounding errors. The C Standard Library provides the [`div(), ldiv(), and lldiv()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.6.2) functions to compute integer division and remainder values in a single operation, so why not take advantage?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1010; i += 500) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            int num = i + j;
            div_t val = div(num, 10);
            printf("%d --> %d.%d\n", num, val.quot, val.rem);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
0 --> 0.0
1 --> 0.1
2 --> 0.2
3 --> 0.3
4 --> 0.4
5 --> 0.5
6 --> 0.6
7 --> 0.7
8 --> 0.8
9 --> 0.9
500 --> 50.0
501 --> 50.1
502 --> 50.2
503 --> 50.3
504 --> 50.4
505 --> 50.5
506 --> 50.6
507 --> 50.7
508 --> 50.8
509 --> 50.9
1000 --> 100.0
1001 --> 100.1
1002 --> 100.2
1003 --> 100.3
1004 --> 100.4
1005 --> 100.5
1006 --> 100.6
1007 --> 100.7
1008 --> 100.8
1009 --> 100.9
```